# Что у нас с [blender]?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, тематика

Я как-то предполагал, что [blender](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blender) у нас онтопик в плане Python и всяких внутренних API. Но иногда проскакивают [вопросы по моделированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887082), и на них иногда [даже отвечают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876967).

Это не очень похоже ни на программирование, ни на администрирование или что-то подобное. При этом голосов за закрытие как-то не особо видно. В итоге я немного в замешательстве — так и до рисования унитазов в 3DS Max недалеко.

Так всё-таки что тут онтопик, а что нет? Мне голосовать за закрытие или не надо? (Если голосовать, то пройдитесь кто-нибудь ещё?)

В [описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/blender/info) бесполезная копипаста из википедии, поменяйте её кто-нибудь

Comment: Что вам всем так неймется что нибудь удалить? Если откровенный бред -- удаляйте. Иначе пройдите мимо. Вот и все

Comment: @avp то есть мы уже не про программирование и не про системное администрирование? Может тогда справку обновить?

Comment: Смотрите на жизнь шире. Мы прежде всего про программирование. А также про все, что нужно для создания программы. Системное администрирование, вспомогательные инструменты (подготовка данных, тестирование, отладка ...) и даже лицензии и требования к документации. Не забывайте, что для написания программы (алгоритма) требуются определенные знания из проблемной области (соответственно, конкретные вопросы по ним также уместны). А справка? Если не лень, обновите.

Comment: @avp ну и какое отношение ко всему перечисленному имеет разрезание овала?

Comment: Могу предположить, что это какой-то шаг в подготовке данных (наверное надо попробовать это выяснить в комментариях у автора вопроса (опять же, если это вас сильно интересует))

Answer (score 5):

На мой взгляд, хорошие вопросы по моделированию вполне могут считаться онтопиком. Если вопрос хорошо воспринят знающими людьми, то он представляет ценность и не стоит его трогать.

Что касается конкретно указанных вопросов:

- Про овал - не могу оценить, т. к. не работаю с ним, а ответа нет.
- Про сочетания клавиш - вопросы про применение инструментов являются онтопиком.

Кстати, я сам задавал несколько вопросов по настройке [visual-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio):

- [Как вернуть старое поведение Ctrl+Click?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/877776/178988)
- [Отключить autoindent в VS 2015+](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763478/178988)
- [Как продолжить скачивание Visual Studio 2017?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739710/178988)

А ещё у нас есть метка [ffmpeg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg), что связано с программированием только тем, что утилита консольная и надо параметры команды подобрать.

Comment: «[тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не относятся к программированию или системному администрированию.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)» — кому верить? (ffmpeg в принципе сюда же)

Comment: @andreymal, никому не верить и оценивать вопрос на основе его полезности. А заброшенные вопросы удаляет Дух. Впрочем, это моя личная позиция.