# Допустимы ли вопросы про настройку среды разработки?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

Наткнулся в очереди на такую проверку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/332253 по этому вопросу: [В WebStorm пропало автодополние](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/938640/15479).

Я смутно припоминаю, что у нас где-то было обсуждение этого вопроса, но не смог ничего найти на мете.

Допустимы ли у нас вопросы про настройку среды разработки? На старшем брате такие вопросы вполне допустимы, насколько я могу судить:

- [No autocomplete on PhpStorm for PHP constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50794738/1991579).
- [PHPStorm auto-complete not working with Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30744564/1991579).
- [PhpStorm and Laravel autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42160204/1991579).

Comment: А где же еще их задавать?

Comment: @avp вон закрывашки указывают в причине, что нужно в саппорт писать.

Comment: Каждый видит сайт со своей колокольни. Пока вопрос не закрыли может кто и успеет помочь стаждущему -)

Comment: @avp если закроют, можно всегда переоткрыть. Но лучше сначала определиться с тем, что сообщество думает на этот счёт.

Comment: Да нет тут единого сообщества. Каждый что-то свое думает.

Comment: @avp хорошо, если думают)

Comment: [вот этот похож?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/225/186999)

Comment: @Grundy похож, но там, во-первых, больше про администрирование, а во-вторых, это было 4 года назад D:

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну IDE - это ПО, вопрос о настройке ПО - все ок

Comment: А этот? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8018/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy там же про моделирование больше.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а в ответе?

Comment: @Qwertiy хотелось, чтоб побольше активных участников высказалось )=

Comment: Вопросам однозначно быть. Среды разработки сложные иногда решения не тривиальные.

Comment: Это типичная задача, которая возникает у программистов непосредственно во время программирования. Конечно да.

Answer (score 13):

**Допустимы**

Тема настройки IDE и сред вполне соответствует правилам:

- эти вопросы для программистов и администраторов
- в большинстве случаев возможно дать четкий ответ
- у нас есть специалисты с большим опытом работы в различных IDE
- у нас уже есть метки по средам и вопросы по ним достаточно неплохи и имеют ответы

Потенциальные подводные камни:

- возникнет желание сделать вопросы про настройку ОС онтопичными. Смотря по реакции на подобные вопросы, они все же считаются оффтопиком.
- зачастую вопросы состоят из скриншотов - с этим надо что-то делать (переводить в текст, улучшать формулировки)

---

См. 338 вопросов с меткой [ide](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide)