# Принимает ли этот сайт больше вопросов, чем Stack Overflow?

Tags: поддержка, тематика

Какие вопросы по теме на этом сайте?

Принимает ли этот сайт больше вопросов, чем Stack Overflow? Например, вопросы по теме на других сайтах Stack Exchange, связанных с компьютерами (например, cs.stackexchange.com, softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, softwarerecommendation.stackexchange.com, unix.stackexchange.com, superuser.com, serverfault.com) ?

Принимаете ли вы концептуальные вопросы информатики?

Comment: Да. Онтопик [настолько запределен и широк](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8018), что я прям в перманентном недоумении нахожусь

Answer (score 6):

Да, многие вопросы, которые закрываются на английском SO, у нас допустимы за отсутвием отдельных сообществ на русском.

Yes, many questions that are closed on English SO are allowed there due to the lack of particular communities in Russian.

Comment: Thanks. Does this site close questions that might be duplicate with SO or SO in other languages?

Comment: @Tim No. On the contrary, we find them very useful.

Comment: How nice!......

Comment: @Tim Yep. Because we build our own "database of knowledge in Russian".

Comment: @Tim If you have some more question like this, you can ping me in [Bots ru.SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115560/bots-on-ru-so).

Comment: Thanks............................

Comment: @Tim please respect the site rules, it is StackOverflow на русском. Пишите по-русски.